# Am I using this respirator correctly?

Tags: respirator

Lately the tree pollen has been really thick in the air. There's a fine yellow powder on every surface. When I breathe it in, especially when mowing the lawn, I start coughing and my throat feels like it's about to close up.  So I am wearing a respirator, but it's not working.

It is fitting tightly against my forehead and temples and jawbone, but it feels like the pollen is still getting into my throat.  It feels as though the pollen-filled air is entering the mask through the exhalation port, which is simply a flap. Is there supposed to be a filter placed into that circular area highlighted in the photo?

The filters are 3M P100 2097 filters.

[image: Exhalation port]

[image: Exhalation port front view]

[image: 3M respirator]

Comment: Also put the lawn mowing clothes directly into the washing machine when you're done.

Comment: https://www.osha.gov/laws-regs/standardinterpretations/1994-05-25  I have to wonder about those studies. In my case, pollen is definitely entering the mask through the exhalation valve.  I cannot measure how much exactly but definitely far more than was coming in via the filters themselves.  The pollen is *not* coming in via an incomplete seal on the face: when I place my thumb over the entire exhalation valve area (the opening near the pink rectangle in photo #2) and breathe in, the mask collapses against my face.  (The exhalation valve is not compromised by paint or other foreign substance.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The exhalation port has a valve (which is typically a thin rubber flap)

Given the design of your filters, you probably need to demount the filters to perform a basic fit and function test by sealing the inlet filter holes (with the palms of your hands, we're not trying to kill you) and inhaling.

If the mask pulls in and you can't get air, all is fitting and working as it should. If you can inhale, you either need a new exhaust port valve, or you have a poor fit. Note that the latter condition is common enough that most industrial site requiring the use of respirators actually have someone who does or oversees the fitting - it's hard to "guess the right size" when ordering online.

Comment: With the respirator pressed against my face with quite a lot of force, more force than the elastic straps typically impart, and my palms against the ports into which the pink filters are screwed, I  breathed in ...   there's a suction pulling  the mask even tighter against my face but still some air getting in.  The exhalation port flap must not be perfectly sealed. If I extend my thumb and block the exhalation-port area, no air comes in.

Comment: This is a pretty new respirator. That it should need a new flap valve is an indication that the exhalation valve is an "Achilles heel" in the design.

Comment: Depending how new, you might try complaining to the manufacturer.

Comment: I will certainly let them know about it.

Comment: @mrblint jam a square piece of soft foam in the outlined area in the second picture ... it may help to keep the flap closed when inhaling

Comment: @mrblint, speaking as someone who wore a gas mask in the military, you shouldn't have to press the mask against your face. In fact, you don't want to test it like that. The test for a good seal is to not have anything pressing the mask against your face, covering the intake holes, and breathing in. Only if your mask still sucks into your face do you have a good seal. The mask should stay on your face without the straps, except in rapid motion. Also, you should be cleaning it with alcohol swabs (the entire inside) in between uses and kept in a sealed bag, too.

Comment: @computercarguy  Pressing the mask against my face with my hand  and blocking the filter ports with my palms was done only in an effort to eliminate an improper face-seal as the cause of air coming in and to show that the exhalation valve was permitting air ingress.  Only after I had blocked the exhalation port as well did air stop coming in.

Comment: @mrblint, if you are having to press the mask against your face "with quite a lot of force, more force than the elastic straps typically impart", then you have an improper fitting mask and you need to find one that fits better. At this point, your exhaust flap is the least of your concerns.

Comment: @computercarguy: I am not having to do that at all.  It was to ensure that absolutely no air was entering via the face seal during the testing to determine whether air was coming in through the exhalation valve when I inhaled.  And now that I've covered the exhalation valve area with fabric cut from an N-95 mask, the problem is gone.  The exhalation valve was indeed the Achilles heel in the design that I suspected it was.